# Is it possible in Rust to delete an object before the end of scope?

Tags: rust

From what I understand, the compiler automatically generates code to call the destructor to delete an object when it's no longer needed, at the end of scope.

In some situations, it is beneficial to delete an object as soon as it's no longer needed, instead of waiting for it to go out of scope. Is it possible to call the destructor of an object explicitly in Rust?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

> Is it possible in Rust to delete an object before the end of scope?

Yes.

> Is it possible to call the destructor of an object explicitly in Rust?

No.

To clarify, you can use [`std::mem::drop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.drop.html) to transfer ownership of a variable, which causes it to go out of scope:

```
struct Noisy;

impl Drop for Noisy {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("Dropping Noisy!");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Noisy;
    let b = Noisy;

    println!("1");

    drop(b);

    println!("2");
}
```

```
1
Dropping Noisy!
2
Dropping Noisy!
```

However, you are forbidden from calling the destructor (the implementation of the `Drop` trait) yourself. Doing so would lead to double free situations as the compiler will still insert the automatic call to the the `Drop` trait.

---

Amusing side note — the implementation of `drop` is quite elegant:

```
pub fn drop<T>(_x: T) { }
```

Comment: What is *destructor* in Rust? Did you mean `drop`?

Comment: @Nawaz [there's no material difference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53324276/155423).  `drop` is just the name of Rust's destructor function.

Answer (score 26):

The official answer is to call [`mem::drop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.drop.html):

```
fn do_the_thing() {
    let s = "Hello, World".to_string();
    println!("{}", s);

    drop(s);

    println!("{}", 3);
}
```

However, note that `mem::drop` is nothing special. Here is [the definition in full](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/mem.rs.html#614):

```
pub fn drop<T>(_x: T) { }
```

That's all.

Any function taking *ownership* of a parameter will cause this parameter to be dropped at the end of said function. From the point of view of the caller, it's an early drop :)

Comment: `drop` is in the prelude; no need to qualify it.

Comment: @Shepmaster: [I remember you pointing out a rare case of `drop` being useful.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36169663/234590) :)