# What is the difference between Rust's Drop and C++'s destructor?

Tags: c++, rust

While reading about the [`Drop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Drop.html) trait, I found a lot of similarities between the `drop` method of Rust and the destructor in a C++. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Rust is not a class-based language, but a trait-based language. Drop is a trait that can be implemented or not. In C++, every class has a destructor, either if you want/need it or not.

Comment: @nbro If we don't implement the Drop trait, wouldn't the compiler do it on its own to get a default version of drop method to free up the memory? Because without that, the system would not be able to free up the memory.

Comment: In safe Rust, you cannot have memory leaks. Rust uses lifetimes to handle the life of "objects". I don't think there's a "default" implementation of the Drop trait for each struct. Rust simply knows the lifetimes of objects and knows when they need to be cleaned up.  See the discussion here: https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/6cognt/do_i_have_to_manually_implement_drop/.

Comment: @nbro Well, you can have memory leaks in safe Rust, but it mostly have to be intentional, unless you mess with weak shared references.

Comment: @Boiethios Ha, ok. We also have this discussion related to this topic: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/memory-leaks-are-memory-safe/5288/3.

Comment: @nbro The [`mem::forget`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.forget.html) function is safe Rust, but you cannot call it unintentionally

Comment: I won't say there's no difference, but the differences are probably trivial. [The documentation for Drop](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Drop.html) even calls it a destructor. Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Yes, even thinking hard, I don't see real differences.

Comment: Well, the differences I mentinoed above are still significant, but this is due to the different design of the languages.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley No. This was the exact precise query. I was just trying to draw a parallel, which in this case is kind of an overlap.

Comment: @nbro: I don't think they really are significant. Just like with drop, you don't have to manually implement a C++ destructor. And just like with drop, the destructors of member objects will still be called, even if you don't. And just like with drop, the "destructors" of trivial objects will do nothing and result in no code being generated.

Comment: The only real difference that I can think of is that C++ has rules about destructors involving inheritance. Since Rust has no inheritance, these rules don't really apply to Rust.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In practice, there is no appreciable difference. Both are used to clean up the resources of a type when appropriate.

> Resources will be cleaned up irrespective of implementation of the `Drop` trait, won't they?

Yes. The compiler *essentially* automatically implements `Drop` for any type where the programmer does not. This automatic implementation simply calls `drop` for each member variable in turn.

If you allocate a resource that Rust doesn't know about, such as allocating memory directly from an allocator, Rust won't know that the returned value needs to be dropped or how to do so. That's when you implement `Drop` directly.

See also:

- [Running Code on Cleanup with the `Drop` Trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch15-03-drop.html)

Comment: Is drop( ) actually used to clean up the resources? Resources will be cleaned up irrespective of implementation of the Drop trait, won't they?

Comment: @ayushprashar: If you make a system call to allocate a resource, for example, to allocate memory, no, that will not be cleaned up for you. The rust compiler wouldn't even know how to clean that up, and it would be presumptuous for it to assume that you wanted it cleaned up and how.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I wasn't intending to convey a system call but a general object declaration within the governing laws of Rust.

Comment: But nowhere in the drop method do we tell the Runtime to return the memory back to the OS, does that automatically happen when ever **drop( )** runs?

Comment: @ayushprashar: By default, calling `Drop` on a pointer does... **nothing**. This is why for classes such as `Vec`, which allocates memory and owns it, a manual `Drop` implementation exists which releases the memory.

Comment: @ayushprashar Local variables are allocated on the stack, and they are automatically deallocated when the stack frame of the current functions is destroyed upon returning from the function. Apart from this the compiler knows about cleaning up memory allocated by `Box`. All other resources need to be deallocated by explicit implementations of `Drop`, including the memory allocated by custom allocators.

Comment: *the compiler knows about cleaning up memory allocated by `Box`* — because [`Box` implements `Drop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-Drop)

Comment: @Shepmaster Here's the implementation of `Drop` for `Box`: `// FIXME: Do nothing, drop is currently performed by compiler.` ☺

Answer (score 0):

The only differences I know of are related to features that C++ has but Rust doesn't. Other folks have mentioned inheritance in the comments above, but a simpler example might be types with multiple constructors. In Rust, depending on what we mean by "constructor", we could say that every type has exactly one constructor (the syntax where you name the type and initialize all its fields). But in C++ a type can have multiple constructors, and importantly, one constructor can *delegate* to another. Here's a quick example:

```cpp
class foo {
public:
  // the inner constructor
  foo(bool throw_in_inner_ctor) {
    if (throw_in_inner_ctor) {
      throw runtime_error("throw in inner ctor");
    }
  }

  // the outer constructor, which delegates to the inner one
  foo(bool throw_in_inner_ctor, bool throw_in_outer_ctor)
      : foo(throw_in_inner_ctor) {
    if (throw_in_outer_ctor) {
      throw runtime_error("throw in outer ctor");
    }
  }

  // the destructor
  ~foo() {
    cout << "foo dtor\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  try {
    cout << "construct a foo that throws in its inner ctor\n";
    foo(true, false);
  } catch (runtime_error) {}
  try {
    cout << "construct a foo that throws in its outer ctor\n";
    foo(false, true);
  } catch (runtime_error) {}
}
```

This prints:

```
construct a foo that throws in its inner ctor
construct a foo that throws in its outer ctor
foo dtor
```

What we're seeing here is that when the inner constructor throws, the destructor of `foo` doesn't get invoked. But when the outer constructor throws, it does. The rule is that our `foo` will get destructed if *any* constructor returns without an exception, regardless of what other delegating constructors might do. Rust has no equivalent to this rule, both because Rust doesn't have delegating constructors, and because constructors in Rust (if you want to call them that) cannot run arbitrary code and cannot fail.