# Is there a way to drop a static lifetime object in Rust?

Tags: rust

When searching for an answer, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42910662/is-it-possible-in-rust-to-delete-an-object-before-the-end-of-scope), however there is no mention of static lifetime objects.  Can the method mentioned in this answer (calling `drop()` on the object) be used for static lifetime objects?

I was imagining a situation like a linked list.  You need to keep nodes of the list around for (potentially) the entire lifetime of the program, however you also may remove items from the list.  It seems wasteful to leave them in memory for the entire execution of the program.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you _want_ to drop something with a static lifetime?

Comment: I was imagining a situation like a linked list.  You need to keep nodes of the list around for potentially the entire lifetime of the program, however you also may remove items from the list.  It seems wasteful to leave them in memory for the entire execution of the program.

I can edit the original question to make this more clear.

Comment: @Slothie If you don't want to keep them in memory for the entire execution time, they're not `static` any more.

Comment: @Slothie You can use lifetimes on the object, which could be `'static`, but isn't necessarily.

Comment: @jhpratt, can you clarify what you mean by "but isn't necessarily"?

Comment: You could still create a `LinkedList<'a>` — `'a` doesn't have to be `'static`.

Comment: I met the same problem. I have a global static `TcpStream` client, and want to impl `Drop` trait for it, to shutdown its sockets when program exits. Since drop a static is not possible, I use `libc::atexit` for cleanup.

Comment: I have the same problem and similar requirement , I found the trait method `Drop::drop()` implemented for a `static` object will NOT be invoked at the end of program , there might be some  ways Rust internally cleans up these static objects I have not found . If you need to do something relying on `Drop` trait,  currently the only option is to avoid declaring an object as `static` variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The very point of a `static` is that it's static: It has a fixed address in memory and can't be moved from there. As a consequence, everybody is free to have a reference to that object, because it's guaranteed to be there as long as the program is executing. That's why you only get to use a `static` in the form of a `&'static`-reference and can never claim ownership.

Besides, doing this for the purpose of memory conservation is pointless: The object is baked into the executable and mapped to memory on access. All that *could* happen is for the OS to relinquish the memory *mapping*. Yet, since the memory is never allocated from the heap in the first place, there is no saving to be had.

The only thing you *could* do is to replace the object using unsafe mutable access. This is both dangerous (because the compiler is free to assume that the object does not in fact change) and pointless, due to the fact that the memory can't be freed, as it's part of the executable's memory mapping.

Comment: This isn’t correct when using `Box::leak()` on a boxed value, which takes a `Box` and pulls it into a `&’static mut`. 

Creating these in a loop will lead to a memory leak.