# Why static items do not call `drop` at the end of the program?

Tags: rust, static

While I was looking into documentation of Rust, there is a statement in [static](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.static.html).

> Static items do not call `drop` at the end of the program.

The way that I understand is if I make `static FOO: Vec<u8> = vec![1, 2, 3];`
then it is not going to free underlying memory.

Could you please explain the reason of this.

Comment: " it is not going to free underlying memory." That's not really a problem as the whole program memory is freed anyway, is it ?

Comment: As the question is about the reason, I think it's clearly explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58141569/is-there-a-way-to-drop-a-static-lifetime-object-in-rust

Comment: It may be noteworthy that you actually *can't* create a (non-empty) `static` `Vec<u8>` since heap allocation can't be done in a `const fn`.